# How use Hide and Show Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

i wanted **pager** is hide and show and *addClas active* 
 1. ***pagerBar*** is hide when i am click **ListButton** and it is **active**.
2.***pagerBar*** is show when i am click **gridButton** and it is is **active**
how use jquery

```
<div class="input-group clearfix">
   <button class="btn active list">list</button>
   <button class="btn grid">grid</button>
</div>
<div class="pager"><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span></div>
<div class="items">
item1 item2 item3 item4
</div>
 <div class="pager clearfix"><span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span> </div>
```

css

```
.input-group{
    border:1px solid red;
    text-align:center;
} 
.items{
   height:300px;
   border:1px solid #ddd;
   margin-top:50px;
   font-size:14pt;
   line-height:400px;
   text-align:center;
   color:red;
}
```

jquery

```
 $(".btn").on('click',function(){
  // it active and hide and show pager
 });
```

## see  [My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/3Yx2p/)

Comment: you can use the `.toggle()` method

Comment: (`^`) Above, or you could: `if($(this).is(':visible')) { HIDE IT} ELSE { SHOW IT}` (*pseudo code*)

Comment: Didn't you even try anything? The `jQuery` documentation for `.show()`, `.hide()` and `.toggle()` are pretty comprehensive and have lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(".btn").on('click',function(){
  $(".btn").removeClass('active');  
  $(this).addClass('active');  
  if($(this).hasClass('list'))
    $('.pager').hide();
  else
    $('.pager').show();
 });
```

OR bind seperate events for `list` and `grid` buttons like below :

```
  $(".list").on('click',function(){
      $(".grid").removeClass('active');  
      $(this).addClass('active');  
        $('.pager').hide();
     });

   $(".grid").on('click',function(){
      $(".list").removeClass('active');  
      $(this).addClass('active');  
        $('.pager').show();
     });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uwmj4/1/)**

Comment: Not a downvoter, but don't use words like __don't be coward__ Voting in SO is anonymous

Answer (score 1):

this should be short and do your task

```
//first check active to see if you have to hide pager before
if ($('.active').hasClass('list')) $(".pager").hide();

//than bind click
$('.btn').on('click', function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(".pager").toggle();
        $(".btn").toggleClass('active');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vf5MK/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 $(".btn").on('click',function(){


        var self = $(this);

        self.addClass("active");
         self.siblings("button").removeClass("active");
        $("div.pager").toggle();

     });
```

here is Demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YacE4/18/

Answer (score 0):

Most basic and simple to understand answer would be:

```
$('.grid').on('click', function() {
 $(this).addClass('active');
 $('.list').removeClass('active');
 $('.pager').show();
});

$('.list').on('click', function() {
 $(this).addClass('active');
 $('.grid').removeClass('active');
 $('.pager').hide();
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ePnAv/

Comment: Please see Dwza's answer for a proper programming answer. Mine does nothing but do exactly as told, his has proper thinking behind it. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use toggle class

```
$(".btn").on('click',function(){
  $(".btn").toggleClass('active');  
  if($(this).hasClass('list'))
    $('.pager').hide();
  else
    $('.pager').show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Yx2p/1/)